# Generating list of all binary strings of size 2n, where the number of 1s in the first n bits equals the number of 1s in the last n bits

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary

For example, given input n=2, I want the output to be ['1111', '1001', '0110', '0000', '0101', '1010']. Note that the order of the output does not matter.

I feel like I should be using a recursive solution, with the base case being when n=1 and returning [00, 11], but I can't figure out the next step. Am I on the right track?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the n=2?   Should that be n=4?

Answer (score 0):

Generate all binary strings of length n, bucket by number of set bits, and take every pair (including an elt with itself) within the buckets.

E.g. for n=2 you have:

```
0: 00
1: 01, 10
2: 11

0x0: 0000
1x1: 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010
2x2: 1111
```